# Repeating each successive element in the input list one more than the previous element

Tags: string, list, haskell

I want to repeat each successive character in the input string one more than the previous character ,starting with a single occurrence of the first character:

for example

```
rep "abcd" == "abbcccdddd"
```

I did this code for ,but this don't work for `String` but produces the correct result for `Int` and `Char`.

```
rep [] =[]
rep (x:xs) =[ (x:xs)!!y| y<-[0..(length xs)]  , _<- [1..y+1]]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could first [`zip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) the list `[1..]` with your list, then apply [`replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) and [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) the results:

```
rep xs = concatMap (uncurry replicate) $ zip [1..] xs
```

Example run:

```
Prelude> let rep xs = concatMap (uncurry replicate) $ zip [1..] xs
Prelude> rep "abcd"
"abbcccdddd"
```

The idea is simple, we associate to every element the number of times it should be repeated.

The `zip` function has type `[a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`, so it takes two lists and returns one list of pairs where the first element is from the first list and the second element is from the second list. In our case we have that the result has type `[(Int, a)]` with `a` depending on the argument.

The `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]` function takes an integer that represents a length and an element `x` and produces a list `[x, x, x, ..., x]` of the given length.

The `uncurry` function takes a function with type `a -> b -> c`, i.e. with two arguments, and transforms it into a function with type `(a, b) -> c`, i.e. with one argument that is a tuple. So `uncurry replicate` has type `(Int, a) -> [a]`.

Now the types match and you could `map` the function over the `zip`ed lists obtaining a `[[a]]` and then using `concat` to concatenate the results. [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) is simply a shorthand for `concat . map`.

Alternatively instead of using `zip` and then `map`ing you can use the [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) function:

```
rep xs = concat $ zipWith replicate [1..] xs
```

---

Note that your solution seems to work correctly:

```
Prelude> let rep [] = []; rep (x:xs) = [ (x:xs)!! y | y <- [0..length xs], _<-[1..y+1]]
Prelude> rep [1,2,3]
[1,2,2,3,3,3]
Prelude> rep "abcd"
"abbcccdddd"
```

If you have an example where it doesn't produce the correct result please *post it in your question*.

However it is inefficient. You should avoid using `!!` and `length` when working with lists and prefer things like `map` and `fold`s.

Moreover I don't believe that the above function can produce the correct result for `[Int]` but not for `String` for one simple reason: the function is polymorphic and thus by parametricity it doesn't matter the type of elements that the list contains, it only matter its length, the result will always have the same shape (if you see the function is never "looking at"/"operating on" the elements, it simply moves them; it does exactly the same thing independently of their specific type.)

Comment: `rep = concat . zipWith replicate [1..]` is a bit shorter.

Comment: @user3237465 You're right. No idea why it didn't come to my mind that I should have used it.